# Angular bootstrap datepicker-popup with disabled input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why `datepicker-popup` doesn't work if the input is disabled? And how can I let it work?

Code:

```
span.input-group
  input.form-control(
    type="text"
    name="accountDate"
    ng-model="account.date"
    min-date="minDate"
    max-date="maxDate"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    ng-disabled="true"
    uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
    is-open="date.isOpen"
    close-text="Close"
    close-on-date-selection="true"
    show-button-bar="false"
  )
  span.input-group-btn
    button.btn.btn-default(
      type="button"
      ng-click="openDatePicker()")
      i.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
```

If I remove `ng-disabled` it works as expected. I tried to replace it with `disabled` and `disabled="disabled"`... not working at all.

I need it to be disabled and if I click on the button it should display the date picker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A disabled input element is unusable and un-clickable. [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp).

Try to use `ng-readonly` instead `ng-disabled`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as expected. In 3 minutes I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround or hack is to place `ng-hide` on the `div` you want to add functionality to and declare a `boolean` in `js` file having value of `true` by default. User clicks on the button and that method should change the value of `boolean` to `false`. Hope this helps!